# Lightning App's description is not updated after package upgrade

Tags: managed-package, lightning-apps

As the title says, Lightning App's description is not updated after the package upgrade. But the documentation states that it's possible...

[image]

Comment: You can change them, but the label, icon and description do not update when upgrading (the new values only appear in a clean install). This is helpful when customers are used to the old name, icon and description, but is annoying too since your app could evolve significantly and warrant the changes being visible for long-term users. Raise an idea if you want to see this capability...

Comment: (You can think of this as like how page layouts work)

Comment: @PhilW Thank you very much! But I can't get the fact that the documentation says that it is possible to update during promotion. At the same time, it says that Page Layouts cannot be updated.

Comment: Raise this with the documentation team, perhaps? The point remains: you can change these aspects of the app, and you can update page layouts, but neither gets applied in an org when upgrading from an earlier version.